# running multiple subdomains on mod_wsgi + apache + pyramid using modwsgi.conf

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, pyramid

I'm attempting to have multiple sub domains name hosting on a domain name, ie. demo1.mydomain.com, demo2.mydomain.com

I've managed to successfully have pyramid running on www.mydomain.com, however, when
I attempted to have a sub domain (demo1.mydomain.com) running another pyramid app,
it isn't hooking up with the pyramid although I've already created and installed 
pyramid project into the folder.

In /usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2_2/mydomain/mydomain.com/modwsgi.conf

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

WSGIPassAuthorization On
WSGIDaemonProcess pyramid_mainsite user=mydomain group=mydomain threads=4 \ 
python-path=/home/mydomain/modwsgi/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/mydomain/modwsgi/env/pyramid_mainsite.wsgi
WSGIScriptAlias /admin /home/mydomain/modwsgi/env/pyramid_mainsite.wsgi

<Directory /home/mydomain/modwsgi/env>
    WSGIProcessGroup pyramid_mainsite
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess pyramid_demo1 user=mydomain group=mydomain threads=4 \
python-path=/home/mydomain/modwsgi/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/mydomain/modwsgi/env/pyramid_demo1.wsgi
WSGIScriptAlias /admin /home/mydomain/modwsgi/env/pyramid_demo1.wsgi

<Directory /home/mydomain/modwsgi/env>
    WSGIProcessGroup pyramid_demo1
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Is that exactly what you have, or are each in separate VirtualHost? It can't work like you have. Also, the /admin sub URL should come before / for same site.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton yes, that is exactly what I have...how should I set it for separate virtualhost for each subdomain? I've extremely limited experience when it comes to servers, apache and stuff, if there is any documents that have details on the A-Z know-how, it is much much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the general Apache documentation and any specific documentation your operating system variant provides about how it specifically sets up Apache configuration directories for sites?